# Generate mock service as HTTP endpoint

Tags: android, http, restful-authentication

I am using this example [login](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-restful-webservice-tutorial-how-to-call-restful-webservice-in-android-part-3/) to build the RESTful part in my application. However, I do not have a server connected. What I want to do is to create a mock service, using an HTTP generator as Mocky ([check it](http://www.mocky.io/)). Does anyone know how can this be achieved? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can also use SOAP UI to mock every kind of Webservices (Soap or Rest): https://www.soapui.org/rest-testing-mocking/rest-service-mocking.html

Comment: Thanks, @gjeanmart! I've just downloaded the trial version. have you used it? May you give me an example/tutorial how this to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for being so long to answer (little bit busy that week). Well, I hope you haven't given up meanwhile...

So below is the procedure to set up a RESTful mock service :

1. You can download the Opensource version of SOAP UI [here](https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui.html). It's enough for making a simple mock service
2. Create a new empty Project
3. Right click on the project and click on "New REST mock service"
4. Right click on MockService1 and click on "Add new mock action"
   [image]

[image]

5. Then double-click on */api/v1/user* and Add a new mock response (right-click / New Mock response)
   [image]
6. It's done. You just need to double-click on "REST MockService1" and run the service (green button)

[image]

You can configure the path, port and host :
[image]

Once running, you're WebService can be called using this HTTP Request : **GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users**

Much more information on the WebSite : https://www.soapui.org/rest-testing-mocking/rest-service-mocking.html
You can for example, define some algorithmes to make your webservice more intelligent and test every case (for example if user is = 1 return 200 OK {user} otherwise return 404 ERROR NOT FOUND, ...)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, explaining. I'll take a close look. At first, what I see, is that I on't have "New REST mock service", but "New REST service from URI". Any idea?

Comment: Could you tell me you have the same menu when you right clock on the Project (left panel)